# Do registers contain address or simply values

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

I just have this conceptual question but I can't really find sites that give clear explanation.

But for the temporary register, saved registers and floating point registers, do they contain address of the values we desire or just the values, say 100 or 200?

Comment: They can contain whatever you want.

Comment: There's no implicit indirection, if that's what you mean.  A pointer is just one kind of value, which you can deref explicitly with a load instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is both. The register can contain an address when used with a `lw` instruction like this:

```
lw $t1, 0($t2) # loads the value at address 0+$t2 into $t1
```

Other instructions involve registers which contain values:

```
add $t1, $t2, $t3 # loads value of $t2 + value of $t3 into $t1
```